# Vanishing viscosity - references

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I want to analyze an initial value problem of the form
$$
\partial_t u(t, x) + F(x, u, \partial_x u) = \varepsilon \partial_x^2 u, \quad u(0,x) = u_0(x)\quad \quad (t, x) \in (0, T) \times \mathbb{R}.
$$
Here, $F$ is smooth in all variables, $\varepsilon >0$ and $u_0 \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. I am interested in a rigorous proof of regularity of this solution.

If one reads e.g. Bressan or similar papers, it is hand-waved that this problem has a $C^\infty$ classical solution. Intuitively, this is also obvious to me. I am rather certain that we even have $W^{\infty, \infty}((0, \infty)\times \mathbb{R})$-solutions, although the proof itself is not that obvious to me.

I have already read lots of literature on this (Godlewski/Raviart, Henry, Lunardi, ...) but I don't really find any satisfactory, rigorous proof especially for this equation.
So are there experts here on parabolic equations that can give me a reference?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you familiar with regularity for the linear forced heat equation $u_t = \varepsilon u_{xx} + f$? Usually you bootstrap regularity for nonlinear equations like this from linear counterparts.

Comment: Yes I am. How exactly can I Transfer the regularity from the Heat equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some hints here, not a full answer. Look, for example, at Section 7.1 in Evans PDE book, which covers higher order regularity for linear parabolic equations, which can be used to bootstrap regularity for nonlinear equations, as described below.

I'll describe it at a high level for elliptic equations, which is simpler since there is no time variable. Consider
$$-\Delta u = f.$$
Ignore boundary conditions for a moment. Then by regularity for elliptic equations we have
$$\|u\|_{H^{k+2}} \leq \|f\|_{H^k}$$
for any $k\geq 0$ ($H^0=L^2$). See Chapter 6 in Evans for this.

We can use this for the nonlinear equation
$$-\Delta u = F(x,u,\nabla u).$$
Suppose you find a weak solution $u\in H^1$ of this equation. Then if $F$ is a nice-enough function, then $f:=F(x,u,\nabla u)$ belongs to $L^2$ (since $u$ and $\nabla u$ belong to $L^2$), and so by elliptic regularity $u\in H^2$. But then $f\in H^1$, and so $u\in H^3$ (and then this gives $f\in H^2$ so $u\in H^4$). You can see this can be continued indefinitely, and so $u\in H^k$ for all $k$, so $u\in C^\infty$.

This procedure is called "bootstrapping". We are using elliptic regularity for linear equations to bootstrap higher regularity for nonlinear equations (i.e., pulling oneself up by their own bootstraps).

For parabolic equations, you can carry out the same procedure, but using the parabolic regularity results in Chapter 7 in Evans. This is a bit more complicated since the regularity in time and space is different. I'll leave this to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look!